# Call shell file from bean shell file

Tags: bash, sh, beanshell

Hey I am very new to shell programming.It is possible to call Shell File from Bean          Shell File. For instance,To shutdown tomcat  **sh shutdown.sh** from BSH file???
How can i do this?????

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exec() ([doc](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#exec)) command in Beanshell